# three.js - Lens Flare and transparency

Tags: three.js, transparency

Currently in my project lens flare is not visible when behind a transparent object, even if the opacity is set to 0. I try to simulate a glass sphere around the camera - but the lens flare is not visible from inside the sphere. Is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set sphere material `depthWrite` to `false`.

```
material.depthWrite = false;
```